# Getting collection object with JOIN FETCH using @Query with Pageable not working - Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Trying to get the Post object using JOIN FETCH with pageable. But its throwing exception.

Entities

```
@Entity
public class Post {
  @Id
  private String postId;
  private String postName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<PostTag> postTags = new HashSet<PostTag>();
}
@Entity
public class Tag {
  @Id
  private String tagId;
  private String tagName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<PostTag> postTags = new HashSet<PostTag>();
}
@Entity
public class PostTag {
  @EmbeddedId
  private PostTagId postTagId = new PostTagId();
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("postId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "post_Id")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Post post;
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("tagId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "tag_Id")
  private Tag tag;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "posttag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Items> items= new HashSet<Items>();

  private String someDateField;
}
@Embeddable
public class PostTagId implements Serializable {
  private String postId;
  private String tagId;
  //equals & hashcode ommited
}
public class Items{
  @Id
  private String itemId;
  private String itemName;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "post_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
  @JsonBackReference
  @JsonIgnore
  private PostTag postTag;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "items", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<SubItems> subItems= new HashSet<SubItems>();

}
public class SubItems{
  @Id
  private String subItemId;
  private String subItemName;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "itemId")})
  @JsonBackReference
  @JsonIgnore
  private Items items;

}
```

Repository query as follows,

Have tried,

```
@Query(value = "select po from Post po INNER JOIN FETCH po.posttags pts INNER JOIN FETCH pts.tag t INNER JOIN FETCH pts.items i INNER JOIN FETCH i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate) order by pts2.someDateField desc", countQuery = "select count(po) from Post po INNER JOIN po.posttags pts INNER JOIN pts.tag t INNER JOIN pts.items i INNER JOIN i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate) order by pts2.someDateField desc")
Page<Post> findAllInOneQuery(String tName, String startDate, String endDate, Pageable pageable);
```

But this results in below exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [po0_.postId.postTags] with element property reference [someDateField]
```

But below List return type works perfectly. Why and how to use the pagination?

```
@Query(value = "select po from Post po INNER JOIN FETCH po.posttags pts INNER JOIN FETCH pts.tag t INNER JOIN FETCH pts.items i INNER JOIN FETCH i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate) order by pts2.someDateField desc", countQuery = "select count(po) from Post po INNER JOIN po.posttags pts INNER JOIN pts.tag t INNER JOIN pts.items i INNER JOIN i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate) order by pts2.someDateField desc")
    List<Post> findAllInOneQuery(String tName, String startDate, String endDate);
```

why List is working as expected but not the Page object. Is there any params missing or do i need to change the query a bit to adapt pageable?

Answer (score 0):

i read your question and here is what i propose:

To use Peagable with `@Query` annotation, you have to specify the countBy property to your Query.

```
@Query(
value = "select po from Post po INNER JOIN FETCH po.posttags pts INNER JOIN FETCH pts.tag t INNER JOIN FETCH pts.items i INNER JOIN FETCH i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate) order by pts2.someDateField desc", countQuery = "select count(po) from Post po INNER JOIN po.posttags pts INNER JOIN pts.tag t INNER JOIN pts.items i INNER JOIN i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate) order by pts2.someDateField desc",
countBy = "select count(po) from Post po INNER JOIN FETCH po.posttags pts INNER JOIN FETCH pts.tag t INNER JOIN FETCH pts.items i INNER JOIN FETCH i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate) order by pts2.someDateField desc", countQuery = "select count(po) from Post po INNER JOIN po.posttags pts INNER JOIN pts.tag t INNER JOIN pts.items i INNER JOIN i.subitems LEFT OUTER JOIN po.posttags pts2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pts.someDateField between :startDate and :endDate)")
Page<Post> findAllInOneQuery(String tName, String startDate, String endDate, Pageable pageable);
```